# Insert data to Firebase and set restriction to UI(username and password) in xamarin form

Tags: c#, validation, xamarin.forms, restriction

I have create acc page in xamarin form. The fields are basic info for customer like firstname, lastname and I have field "username" and "password". So it goes like this. I want to set a rule for;

1. Username;
   -no duplication for username. Because every username inputted by customer, It check in database if that username is avail or not.
   Example, username: dummy123

I want this way for username;
-upon tapping the entry field for username, and assume customer will input "dummy123" a toast will appear like "username already exist"

2. Password;
   -password must contain; capital letter, small char, special char, number and 8 letter and above.

I want this way for password;
-upon tapping the entry field for password, and assume customer will input "@imcool123" a toast will appear like this; "password must contain capital letter, small char, special char, number and 8 letter and above"

any link posted will be appreciated. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow the steps below to make your ideas work.

First, you can create a model for deserializing your response.

```
 public class Person  
    {  
        public string Name { get; set; }  
    }
```

Second, you can write the code to connect the Firebase Realtime Database.

```
using Firebase.Database;  
using Firebase.Database.Query;  
  
FirebaseClient firebase = new FirebaseClient("https://");
```

Third, create an Entry with `TextChanged` in the `MainPage.xaml`.

```
 <StackLayout>
        <Entry x:Name="EntryText" TextChanged="EntryText_TextChanged" />
 </StackLayout>
```

Fourth, fulfill the `EntryText_TextChanged` method in `MainPage.xaml.cs`. The method provide a way to match the data which in the Firebase.

```
 public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
 
 public async Task<List<Person>> GetAllPersons()  
    {  

        return (await firebase  
          .Child("Persons")  
          .OnceAsync<Person>()).Select(item => new Person  
          {  
              Name = item.Object.Name,  
              PersonId = item.Object.PersonId  
          }).ToList();  
    }  

        private void EntryText_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var oldText = e.OldTextValue;
            var newText = e.NewTextValue;

            var person = await firebaseHelper.GetPerson(Convert.ToString(EntryText.Text);
            if (person != null)
            {
                
                EntryText.Text = person.Name;
                // this is a Toast method
                await DependencyService.Get<IToast>().ShortAlert("username already exist");

            }
            else
            {
                
            }
        }
// This is the method to find the name if it has existed
        public async Task<Person> GetPerson(string personName)
        {
            var allPersons = await GetAllPersons();
            await firebase
              .Child("Persons")
              .OnceAsync<Person>();
            return allPersons.Where(a => a.PersonName == personName).FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
```

In addition, here is the information about the [Xamarin.Forms - How To Make Toast Message Using Dependency Service](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/xamarin/). You can check this article.

Comment: Thank you so much sir, you answer is helpful to me. For now, I will just keep your answer and I will look it again cause ATM Im still learning firebase, like how it's structure, and after that, I will work my registration page. I will reply here soon. Thank you so much sir.

Comment: You are welcome. If you have any questions, please feel free to ask.

Comment: hello sir, can I ask a question? its not related to my post but its connected to my capstone/thesis, if it ok?

Comment: My question sir, I make a map and I run it on emulator in xamarin form,I can locate my location but lately I try to run it on my physical device since our defense is approaching so I want to try it,so I run the app, it run normally but when I get my location, it says "unknown location" any idea sir how to solve it? Thank you sir.

Comment: Sorry @Newbie _XamForm, you should start a new thread for new question. We should adhere to Stack Overflow's rules. But you can check this [How to use Google Maps and Location with Xamarin.Android](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/maps-and-location/maps/) for more information.

Comment: oh I see, sorry sir, thanks for idea about stackover's rule and also  thanks for the link you posted.

Comment: hello sir, Im working it rn,  var allPersons = await GetAllPersons(); where the GetAllPersons() from? cause I got an error right there, it said, it doesnt exist in the context, thanks.

Comment: I update the code. I miss the method GetAllPersons().

Comment: Thank you sir, I look for getallpersons at internet but I havnt seen any link huhu sorry for bothered sir.

Comment: 'FirebaseClient' does not contain a definition for 'GetCustomer' and no accessible extension method 'GetCustomer' accepting a first argument of type 'FirebaseClient' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) what does it mean sir? var customerName = await firebaseClient.GetCustomer(Convert.ToString(entryField_Username.Text)); // the error is in this line

Comment: I updated the answer, and you can find the `GetCustomer` method in the answer I posted.

Comment: thank you sir. The code you posted is good, I actually run it however i got an error, I have a new post here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74758746/insert-data-to-firebase-and-set-restriction-to-uiusername-and-password-in-xama/74781614#74781614

Comment: I try your codes sir and it run but still I can insert data to firebase realtime with the same username :(